# How to use document.getelementbyId when element is in a different component?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have this landing page where I have a form and a function that needs to be triggered when the form is submitted.
Here's the function:

```
async function sendWaitlistData() {
        const name_input = document.getElementById("name") as HTMLInputElement;
        const name_arr = name_input.value.split(" ");
        var first_name = name_arr[0];
        for (let i = 0; i < name_arr.length - 2; i++) {
            first_name = first_name.concat(" ", name_arr[i + 1]);
        }
        const email = document.getElementById("email") as HTMLInputElement;
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://${window.location.hostname}/addWaitlist`,
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email.value,
                    first_name: first_name,
                    last_name: name_arr[name_arr.length - 1],
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            }
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Please enter valid email address and name.");
        }
    }
```

And, this is my `App.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.svelte";
    import HeroSection from "./components/HeroSection.svelte";
    import WhatWeAreBuilding from "./components/WhatWeAreBuilding.svelte";
    import Footer from "./components/Footer.svelte";
    import FaqBlock from "./components/FAQBlock.svelte";
    import SecondCta from "./components/SecondCTA.svelte";
    async function sendWaitlistData() {
        const name_input = document.getElementById("name") as HTMLInputElement;
        const name_arr = name_input.value.split(" ");
        var first_name = name_arr[0];
        for (let i = 0; i < name_arr.length - 2; i++) {
            first_name = first_name.concat(" ", name_arr[i + 1]);
        }
        const email = document.getElementById("email") as HTMLInputElement;
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://${window.location.hostname}/addWaitlist`,
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email.value,
                    first_name: first_name,
                    last_name: name_arr[name_arr.length - 1],
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            }
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Please enter valid email address and name.");
        }
    }
</script>

<main>
    <div class="bg-black flex flex-col pb-10">
        <Navbar />
        <HeroSection waitListFunction={sendWaitlistData()}/>
    </div>
    <hr class="border border-gray-300 w-full mx-auto" />
    <WhatWeAreBuilding />
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-[#323232] mb-2">
        <FaqBlock />
    </div>
    <SecondCta waitListFunction={sendWaitlistData()}/>
    <Footer />
</main>

<style>
</style>
```

The form is in the component called `SecondCta` and `HeroSection`. I'm using `document.getElementbyId("")` in my async function. During runtime, I'm getting an error that the value of "name" is null. it's probably because I'm passing this function as a prop to other components. So, what do I do so that I can use this function in App.svelte and pass it on to other components with this form without having this error?

I could have just copy pasted it in both the components, but I don't want repetition of code.

Answer (score 2):

This is not passing the function, it calls it and thus passes its return value:

```html
<HeroSection waitListFunction={sendWaitlistData()}/>
```

If you want to pass it as a callback you need to pass it like this:

```html
<HeroSection waitListFunction={sendWaitlistData}/>
```

I would not recommend doing this though. You create a dependency between the function and and various internals of components that should not be coupled. Instead the component could use prop [bindings](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-property) or [fire an event](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-createeventdispatcher) and pass all relevant values as part of the event data. With Svelte you should not query the DOM and ideally use something like `bind:value` on inputs or use their events (e.g. `change` or `input`).

If you really need access to DOM elements you can use [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-this) or get them from various events (e.g. via `event.target`).